# Post from my app appears on the page's wall, but the users who liked that page can't see in their newsfeed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app to post on my fan page, it works perfectly.

My problem is when I post on my fan page with my app, the new post appears on the page's wall, but the users who liked that page can't see in their newsfeed...

Is there a new Graph API restriction or something like that?

I wrote my app with the facebook's PHP sdk.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found the problem...

When a facebook's user press the "like" button in your fan page automatically is checked the "Show in news feed"  option and then the user is able to receive the new posts from your facebook page in his wall. In my case (I don't know why) the "Show in news feed"  option is not automatically checked, the user needs to mark manually the option to recieve my new post from my fan page.

Here is some articles about this topic:

http://antoniocalero.com/2012/08/24/show-in-news-feed-myth/

http://alwaysupward.com/blog/fb-fans-arent-seeing-your-posts-and-how-to-fix-it/comment-page-2/

I hope this helps someone.

And I'm sorry for my bad English.